# Is there a partial recursive function mapping $e$ to the least element of $W_e$?

Tags: logic, computability

Is there a partial recursive function $f$ that maps $e$ to the least element of $W_e$ if $W_e\neq \varnothing$?

Can we apply the $\mu$-operator (minimization) to a partially decidable predicate to get a partial recursive function (as in defining $f(x)=\mu z(z\in W_e)$ if $W_e\neq\varnothing$ and undefined otherwise, since $z\in W_e$ is partially decidable)?

My guess was that there is no such $f$, but I wasn't sure how to show that.
Thanks in adavnce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is right: there is no such function.

We can see this in a couple different ways:

- **Contradiction**: Suppose there were such an $f$. Then - given an arbitrary (infinite) c.e. set $A$ - we could compute the sequence $$\min(A), \min(A\setminus\{\min(A)\}), \min(A\setminus\{\min(A), \min(A\setminus\{\min(A)\})\}), ...$$ by iteratively applying $f$. But this precisely enumerates $A$ in order, and so makes $A$ computable. Since there are non-computable sets, this can't happen.
- **Direct diagonalization**: Given a computable function $f$, we can find an $e$ such that $(i)$ $2$ enters $W_e$ at stage $0$, $(ii)$ $1$ enters $W_e$ at stage $n+1$ iff $f(e)$ halts and outputs "$2$" at stage exactly $n$, and $(iii)$ no other numbers enter $W_e$ under any other circumstances. Then we get $\min(W_e)=2$ iff $f(e)\not=2$, so $f$ doesn't do what we want it to.

  - This fits into the "game picture" of c.e. sets: I pick a computable $f$, and you start building my $W_e$. You put $2$ into it, which forces me to eventually decide what $f(e)$ is; as soon as I do, if I say "$2$" then you put $1$ into my set, and if I say anything other than "$2$" you do nothing. Either way, you've defeated my purported $f$.

I haven't provided full details of either case, but the idea should be clear. Filling in the details (of the first one, especially) is a good exercise.

Comment: I haven't seen much of the "game" arguments, so could you explain what you mean by we "build $W_e$"? Isn't $W_e$ already determined for each $e$? Also, what do you mean by we can "find" $e$ such that 2 enters $W_e$ at stage 0... and so on?

Comment: @user500144 The two key ingredients here are Church's thesis and, more subtly, the **recursion theorem**. It's the latter which lets us seemingly "define $e$ while knowing already $e$."

Comment: Specifically, the argument has two pieces. Suppose $f$ has the property proposed. We begin with a Church's thesis argument: there is a total computable $h$ such that, for each $e$, we have $W_{h(e)}=\{1,2\}$ if $f(e)\downarrow=2$ and $W_{h(e)}=\{2\}$ otherwise.

Comment: (cont'd) The interesting step is applying the Recursion Theorem. Since $h$ is total computable, it has a fixed point - some $c$ such that $W_c=W_{h(c)}$. But then we have $W_{c}=\{1,2\}$ if $f(c)\downarrow=2$ and $W_c=\{2\}$ otherwise - contradicting the assumption on $f$.

Comment: (contd) The recursion theorem aside (it is genuinely a technical result), all of this stuff becomes more intuitive once you think of c.e. sets as sets you can "enumerate effectively." E.g. intuitively we can effectively enumerate the theorems of a given (computably axiomatizable) theory: just search through all possible proofs and put sentences into the set we're building when we see them proved. This corresponds to the fact that the set of (Godel numbers of) theorems of a (computably axiomatizable) theory is c.e. So it's a useful intuitive device: if you can build it, it's $W_e$ for some $e$.